# How can I detect when scrolling has started in a ListView on Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'd like to subscribe to an event which tells me that scrolling has started in a ListView and get the direction of scrolling.

Is there any way to do this in Windows 10 UWP API?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should first [obtain](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/PullToRefreshUWP_WindowsComposition/blob/master/PullToRefreshXaml/Extensions.cs#L9) the `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListView` and then subscribe to its `DirectManipulationStarted` event.

However, to get the direction of the scrolling can be tricky. I'd suggest you to have a look at the new Windows Composition API where there's a way to use `ExpressionAnimation` to link the `ScrollViewer`'s translation to a value of your choice.

A good start is to have a look at this [demo](https://github.com/clarkezone/UWPCompositionDemos/tree/master/XAML-ParallaxDemo) from James Clarke.

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CompositionPropertySet scrollerViewerManipulation = ElementCompositionPreview.GetScrollViewerManipulationPropertySet(myScroller);

    Compositor compositor = scrollerViewerManipulation.Compositor;

    ExpressionAnimation expression = compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation("ScrollManipululation.Translation.Y * ParallaxMultiplier");

    expression.SetScalarParameter("ParallaxMultiplier", 0.3f);
    expression.SetReferenceParameter("ScrollManipululation", scrollerViewerManipulation);

    Visual textVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(background);
    textVisual.StartAnimation("Offset.Y", expression);
}
```

### Update

Actually just thought of an easier way to detect the scrolling direction. Just subscribe whenever the `VerticalOffset` is changed and compare it to its previous values.

```
private double _previousOffset;  

sv.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(ScrollViewer.VerticalOffsetProperty, (s, dp) =>
{
    if (Math.Abs(sv.VerticalOffset - _previousOffset ) < 3)
    {
        // ignore when offset difference is too small
    }
    else if (sv.VerticalOffset > _previousOffset)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"up {sv.VerticalOffset - _previousOffset}");
    }
    else {
        Debug.WriteLine($"down {sv.VerticalOffset - _previousOffset}");
    }

    _previousOffset = sv.VerticalOffset;
});
```

Comment: Why is everyone and their dog dead-set on using the `VerticalOffset` property, to then try to evaluate the direction of a manipulation? This is trying to re-invent the manipulation processor. And doing it poorly at that. The **real** state machine is ***way*** more complex than this (it needs to reset itself for each distinct manipulation, for example, which you are ignoring, but there's lots, lots more).

Comment: @IInspectable dude, your answer is wrong cause SV's implementation prevents you from getting the all non direct manipulation events. That's why most people use the offset. You want 100% accurate output? As ALSO EXPLAINED in my answer, use Composition API.

Comment: @IInspectable the Offset from the SV Comp property is also updated without any latency compared to the dp VerticalOffset.